# Making variables in a procedure global

Tags: vb.net

I know the title seems pretty trivial but i have an issue and i can't seem to get round it, i have the following code within one sub procedure..

```
  Dim X, Y As Integer
    X = 32
    Y = 285

    X_coords(0) = X       ' x1 (a1)
    X_coords(1) = X - 13  ' x2 (a2)
    X_coords(2) = X + 16  ' x3 (a3)
    X_coords(3) = X + 63  ' x4 (b1)
    X_coords(4) = X + 45  ' x5 (b2)
    X_coords(5) = X + 74  ' x6 (b3)
    X_coords(6) = X + 124 ' x7 (c1)
    X_coords(7) = X + 103 ' x8 (c2)
    X_coords(8) = X + 132 ' x9 (c3)
    X_coords(9) = X + 63  ' x10 (b4)
    X_coords(10) = X + 76 ' x11 (y3)
    X_coords(11) = X + 21  ' x12 (n1)
    X_coords(12) = X + 9 ' x13 (q1)
    X_coords(13) = X + 65 ' x14 (q3)
    X_coords(14) = X + 117 ' x14 (q5)
    X_coords(15) = X + 87 ' x14 (q4)
    X_coords(16) = X + 31 ' x13 (q2)
    X_coords(17) = X + 139 ' x13 (q6)
    X_coords(18) = X + 76 ' x13 (q6)
    X_coords(19) = X + 129 ' x13 (q6)


    Y_coords(0) = Y        ' y1s1
    Y_coords(1) = Y - 23   ' y1s2
    Y_coords(2) = Y - 11.5 ' y1,2s
    Y_coords(3) = Y - 47   ' y2s1
    Y_coords(4) = Y - 70   ' y2s2
    Y_coords(5) = Y - 59 ' y2,2s 
    Y_coords(6) = Y - 132  ' y4s1
    Y_coords(10) = Y - 152  ' y4s2
    Y_coords(7) = Y - 140 ' y4 30cred
    Y_coords(8) = Y - 127 ' y4s1, 10cred
    Y_coords(9) = Y - 105 ' y3



    Dim a1 As New posData("a1", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
    Dim a2 As New posData("a2", X_coords(1), Y_coords(0)) 
    Dim a3 As New posData("a3", X_coords(2), Y_coords(0))
    Dim a4 As New posData("a4", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
```

I do know how to create global variable within your class, I want to make a1, a2 etc global but they must take the values of the said X_coords and Y coords, i dont know how to make this global so that it will do so.. the values are blank because i cannot initialize them globally?

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a1, a2... as a global variable (whatever you mean by global). Then in the class' constructor you can assign a value to them:

```
Sub New()
    '....
    a1 = New ...
    '....
```

If these variables are shared, you can use the shared constructor.

If the variables need to be recalculated, it probably would be a good idea to make them readonly properties.

Answer (score 0):

The question would be global to what?  The class itself?

```
Public Class MyClass

Private a1 As posData
Private a2 As posData
Private a3 As posData
Private a4 As posData

Public Function SetVariables()

    'blah blah

    a1 = New posData("a1", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
    a2 = New posData("a2", X_coords(1), Y_coords(0))
    a3 = New posData("a3", X_coords(2), Y_coords(0))
    a4 = New posData("a4", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
End Function
```

End Class

The variables are available to any function in the current instance of that class.

Global to your application?

```
Public Class MyClass

Public Shared a1 As posData
Public Shared a2 As posData
Public Shared a3 As posData
Public Shared a4 As posData

Public Function SetVariables()

    'blah blah

    a1 = New posData("a1", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
    a2 = New posData("a2", X_coords(1), Y_coords(0))
    a3 = New posData("a3", X_coords(2), Y_coords(0))
    a4 = New posData("a4", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
End Function
```

End Class

Now they are static and shared across all instances of the class.

Hope that helps.